# Android RecyclerView, recycling not working properly

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I have a `RecyclerView` that I am using. I have used `RecyclerView` before but never had this problem.

When I scroll up and down some of the items disappear, and some of the items that disappear appear again in the bottom.

Code:

`ViewHolder`:

```
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public TextView txt;

    public ViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        txt = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt);
    }
}
```

`Adapter`:

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ViewHolder> {
    private final Activity activity;
    private final ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mItems;

    public MyAdapter (Activity activity, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mItems) {
        this.activity = activity;
        this.mItems= mItems;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        return new ViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(activity).inflate(R.layout.items, viewGroup, false));
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
        HashMap<String, String> item = mItems.get(position);

        String info = item.get("info ");
        if (info!= null) {
            viewHolder.txt.setText(info);
        } else {
            viewHolder.txt.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return (null != mItems? mItems.size() : 0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`onBindViewHolder` reuses Views so let's say the first time `onBindViewHolder()` is called, `info` is `null`. This will cause that row to have visibility of `View.GONE`.

When `onBindViewHolder` is called again to bind a new row, the view for that row is still `View.GONE` - nothing is reset between rows being bound.

Therefore your if statement should reset the state completely:

```
if (info!= null) {
    viewHolder.txt.setText(info);
    viewHolder.txt.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
} else {
    viewHolder.txt.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

This will ensure that each row's visibility is set correctly.