# when i scroll up an down in Recyclerview recycling not working properly

Tags: android

**This is my code

when i scroll up and down, images add on other position too even at those position images path doesn't exist. suppose images paths are at 1,2 and at 3 position but it also showing image at 4,10,15 position etc**

```
public class Contact_Adapter_RecyeckView extends
RecyclerView.Adapter<Contact_Adapter_RecyeckView.ViewHolder> {
private ArrayList<ContactBean> arraylist;
private Context context;

public Contact_Adapter_RecyeckView(Context context,
        ArrayList<ContactBean> arrayListImages) {
    this.arraylist = arrayListImages;
    this.context = context;
}

// Create new views (invoked by the layout manager)
@Override
public Contact_Adapter_RecyeckView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(
        ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    // create a new view
    View itemLayoutView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(
            R.layout.contact_adapter_recycleview, null);

    // create ViewHolder

    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(itemLayoutView);
    return viewHolder;
}

// Replace the contents of a view (invoked by the layout manager)
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, int pos) {

    String image = arraylist.get(pos).getImage();

         File imgFile = new  File(image);
            if(imgFile.exists())
            {

                viewHolder.ivProfile.setImageURI(Uri.fromFile(imgFile));

            }


        //viewHolder.ivProfile.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(arraylist.get(pos).getImage()));
        //viewHolder.ivProfile.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); 

// inner class to hold a reference to each item of RecyclerView
public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public ImageView ivProfile;
    public View view;
    public CardView cardview;

    public ViewHolder(View itemLayoutView) {
        super(itemLayoutView);

        ivProfile = (ImageView) itemLayoutView
                .findViewById(R.id.iv_user_profile);


    }
}

// Return the size of your itemsData (invoked by the layout manager)
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return arraylist.size();
}}
```

**i have seen this links too some others too but still problem is same** [scroll when change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29324873/android-recyclerview-recycling-not-working-properly) couldn't find

Comment: Maybe because `imgFile.exists()` return `false`, try set a default image in else bloc.

Comment: image variable contains blank if there is not imagepath

Comment: You need to reset the default image ( the blank image) in else bloc, otherwise the recycling mechanism will re-use an old one.

Comment: thanks its working fine. :-) you save a lot my time.

Comment: my stackoverflow reputation is only one for accept i need miminum 15 :-(

Comment: You don't need 15 reputation to accept an answer, you just click on checkmark near to the answer. (15 reputation is for upvote privilege)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to reset the default image in `else` bloc, otherwise the recycling mechanism will re-use an old image.

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, int pos) {

    String image = arraylist.get(pos).getImage();
    File imgFile = new  File(image);
       if(imgFile.exists()){
          viewHolder.ivProfile.setImageURI(Uri.fromFile(imgFile));
       } else {
         // here you set your default image, or you can just hide "viewHolder.ivProfile"
       }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you receive recycled views in `onBindViewHolder()`, the `ImageView` may carry data from previous initialization, so you need to explicitly hide/clear the `ImageView` if there's no data for the current item:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, int pos) {
    String image = arraylist.get(pos).getImage();
    File imgFile = new  File(image);
    if(imgFile.exists()) {
        viewHolder.ivProfile.setImageURI(Uri.fromFile(imgFile));
    } else {
        viewHolder.ivProfile.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
}
```

Comment: when i set invisible it works fine but what i want if doesn't contain path it should show default image that is already set.

Comment: thanks its working fine. :-) you save a lot my time. instead of invisible i set default image in else block. else block worked for me.

Comment: Glad it helped! Please accept the answer if it worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

First of all
When you write a condition inside `onBindViewHolder` you must write the your action on condition alternative also.
Such as

```
if(condition){
    //Write your code for condition is true
}else{
    //Write your code if condition is false
}
```

You may have not get proper result only doing this ...
Because first time to show view in `onBindViewHolder` use assigning your resource and second time it use cache...
In my case it happened so,
To solve this problem write the code bellow...

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, int pos) {
 //To stop recycle 
 holder.setIsRecyclable(false);

 //your code
 ...........

 //your conditional work
 if(condition){
    //Write your code for condition is true
 }else{
    //Write your code if condition is false
 }
}
```