# Why are these recyclerview items not filling their views?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-scrollview

I have a horizontal RecyclerView inside a NestedScrollView inside a SwipeRefreshLayout. Presumably this is a cause for error. When I load the data the children display fine but once I scroll to an end and rescroll the children aren't filling their views.

[In action](https://media.giphy.com/media/3ov9k7YzvMrt74t8I0/giphy.gif)

I've found a bunch of different advice on how to fix this with layout constraints, different parent view types, and changing focus but the problem still occurs. onBindViewHolder is definitely getting called but for some reason the binding doesn't happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue: In my viewholder I set certain layouts as invisible and since the views are recycled they weren't showing. All I had to do was set them to visible.

From this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/29325270/6136947

Answer (score 0):

This strange happened because of recycling process for the recycler view, all layout code written at the bind view (in the View holder) will ignored on recycling, and to solve it, add this code:

```
RecyclerView.setRecyclerListener(new RecyclerView.RecyclerListener() {
            @Override
            public void onViewRecycled(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder) {
                    ((BusinessChildViewHolder) holder).onBind();
                    // onBind method inside your holder and it just applies the layout changes that you need
            }
        });
```